# Autocomplete 403s when behind a proxy

Tags: 7, entities, ajax

I've got a virtualbox VM setup as a proxy server between Drupal to try to replicate a CDN causing errors on a client's machine.

My current port is as follows: `http://site-name.dd:9999`

When I go to the proxy-enabled site, and try to use a given entity reference, I get a 403 error:

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 403
Debugging information follows.
Path: http://site-name.dd:8086/index.php?q=entityreference/autocomplete/single/field_guardians/participant/player/NULL
StatusText: Forbidden
ResponseText: 
Access denied | Site Here
Skip to main content
Site Title Here
Main menuName
Another Name
A Third Name
Products
Access denied                                        You are not authorized to access this page.
```

My guess is that this is due to me trying to access via port 9999, and the direct site being on 8086.

I believe a similar (though perhaps not exact issue) is also facing the client. How do I deal with this AJAX error? Has anyone seen anything like this?

This is for a D7 site.

EDIT:

I have also tried changing these settings in settings.php:

```
$conf['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;
```

And alternatively setting one of these two and testing with each, with no success:

```
$conf['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = array('10.1.0.157');

$conf['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

EDIT 2:

From what I can find, the error is because it is getting the original server port from the autocomplete field input element value. So either I need a way for the 8086 port to recognize the 9999 port as legitimate or I need to switch to the 9999 port as correct.

Comment: What happens when you hit the path in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some pointers:

- Set a global `$base_url = 'http://example.com:9999'` as mentioned by Clemens Tolboom. This should be the easiest.
- Implement [hook_url_outbound_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7.x) and change the `options.base_url` as per your requirements (for every internal request).
- Configure the server to work with both the ports? I wonder why are you using 2 ports for the same site though

Answer (score 2):

You should set your Base URL to

```
$base_url="http://site-name.dd:9999";
```

From default.settings.php

> If Drupal is generating incorrect URLs on your site, which could
>    be in HTML headers (links to CSS and JS files) or visible links on pages
>    (such as in menus), uncomment the Base URL statement below (remove the
>    leading hash sign) and fill in the absolute URL to your Drupal installation.

Comment: Is there anyway to make this work without doing this?

Comment: This is the easiest way to solve the problem. Why would you want to do it a different way?

Comment: There are not much options left. You could conditional set $base_url on intranet needs or you could use https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7.x to code a different strategy which is used by https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7.x where the $option['base_url'] marked as _internal_. Make sure then to use $options['absolute'] = true ... that road will be bumpy.

Comment: This works when you are using cloudflare. I have an SSL drupal 7 installation sending data to cloudflare. Cloudflare caches the d7 SSL site for me. When I began this, all autocomplete fields stopped working. I also added a rule in cloudflare to not cache the admin pages where my autocomplete fields mostly are (plus node/add* and node/edit*). Excellent answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can set your reverse proxy settings in your web server configuration with the port details. It will work and will not cause any error on autocomplete field.

For apache:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>  
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

SSLProxyVerify none 
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto 'https'

ProxyPass "/" "https://base-url/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "https://base-url/"
ProxyHTMLURLMap "https://base-url/" "/"

<Location />
    ProxyPassReverse /
    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    ProxyHTMLURLMap / /
    RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
</Location>
```